# Parameterized mysql.connector query

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

Previously, I parameterized my queries with pyodbc successfully. Now I'm trying to do the same in mysql.connector (python). Without the parameterization, the query runs fine. Below is my query, with one '%s' shown that I want to replace with a string containing a number, for example:'17360'

```
query = 
'''SELECT meas.pk_measurement
    FROM tbl_basic_patient pat
    JOIN tbl_basic_examination exam ON pat.pk_patient = exam.fk_patid 
    WHERE pat.patientid = %s 
    ORDER BY meas.pk_measurement'''



def query_l(query,pid):
    try:
        conn = mysql.connect(**database)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, pid)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    finally:
        conn.close()
    return result

query_l(query,('17360'))
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting a mysql syntax error and I keep going in circles figuring out my error. Online I found that %s should be replaced by a tuple. Could any of you give me a hint on how to resolve my error?

Answer (score 0):

Your're correct: you need a tuple (or a dictionary) as the second parameter to `cursor.execute()`.  [Docs here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html).

Try this:

```py
cursor.execute(query, (pid,))
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot O. Jones. I thought it was something as simple as that.